# About separated CSS files

Tags: css

I have a website, and its separated between sections, my question is:

Is it a good pratice to separate the css files for each section?

Ps.: I have a 'global' css stylesheet.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not about asking whether something is good practice or not. A question should address specific programming problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is it you mean by *sections*?

General practice (as far as I know) is to have one global style sheet to style the entire look of the site.

From there you can use combinations of minimal inline styling if needed and perhaps other style sheets for specific "plugin" like objects or sections.

In the end it's your call. There are pros and cons to any way you approach it.

With one giant containing style sheet, maintainability can become difficult. Searching through thousands of line of code 3 months later when you need to make a minor tweak is a bit tough.

On the other side, many smaller style sheet means more external file calls from the website, which can slow load times (minimally).

My personal recommendation for using style sheets, use whatever method makes maintainability easiest. Use lots of comments and logical ordering.

Answer (score 0):

For development I would say it is a good practice as it is easier to find what you are looking for faster or to point other developers to where they need to change some code.  You can then bring in CSS preprocessors such as LESS and SASS to "build" your CSS for deployment only.

Answer (score 0):

It depends...

If you feel that people may only visit one section of the site, you could avoid overhead by only serving the stylesheet for that section.

If a user will bounce around between the sections, they will need both stylesheets and it makes sense to merge them.

As far as best practices are concerned, there aren't any one size fits all for segmenting CSS. It is generally accepted to just try and minimize HTTP requests and file size as well as reusing code as often as possible. Other than that, you can use your best judgement.